# ASP.NET jQuery File Upload plugin blueimp doesn't allow uploads or deletes

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, upload, blueimp

I'm trying too integrate blueimp jQuery File upload into my my .NET site and I'm using jQuery 1.10. I found a .NET example project on blueimp ([Link](https://github.com/i-e-b/jQueryFileUpload.Net)) which works when run on it's own as a separate project but when I move the code to my own site, things don't work as expected.

This project uses jQuery 1.6 but I use 1.10. This may be an issue as things have changed in the jQuery framework since 1.6.

I've managed to make it work so that it lists files but the upload and delete functionality fail. More specifically when I click the delete icon, the console on inspect element says:

> Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/[PATH]/FileTransfer.ashx?f=file.pdf

When trying to upload, I get an error:true.

I've tried to download the latest blueimp plugin and integrate it with my site but I can't seem to make it work ad that's why I went on to use the older .NET project I mentioned above.

It would be great if someone could help. Any ideas?